# Deadlock on stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, delphi

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server. When I execute it from Delphi I get a deadlock message!

> Transaction (Process ID 60) was deadlocked on lock | generic waitable object resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim

What should I change in the query below in order to fix this situation. My stored procedure has no parameters.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RepairStocks] 
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   drop table [dbo].[stocksss]

   select  
       Barkod, 
       sum(kolicina) as Kolicina, 
       Max(Kategorija) as Kategorija,
       Max(Artikal) as Artikal, 
       Max(Opis) as Opis, 
       Max(N_cena) as N_cena,
       Max(N_cena) * sum(kolicina) as N_Iznos, 
       Max(P_cena) as P_cena, 
       Max(P_Cena) * sum(kolicina) as P_Iznos, 
       Max(datum) as datum, 
       Max(Golemina) as Golemina
    into [dbo].[stocksss]
    from [dbo].[Stocks]
    group by Barkod

    drop table [dbo].[Stocks];

    select *
    into [dbo].[Stocks]
    from [dbo].[stocksss]   

END
```

Any help is much appreciated...

**After editing my query**

The query below works on SQL Server, however I get the deadlock message again when I execute this from Delphi. This is how my query looks:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RepairStocks] 

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

BEGIN TRAN

select  
Barkod, 
sum(kolicina) as Kolicina, 
Max(Kategorija) as Kategorija,
Max(Artikal) as Artikal, 
Max(Opis) as Opis, 
Max(N_cena) as N_cena,
Max(N_cena) * sum(kolicina) as N_Iznos, 
Max(P_cena) as P_cena, 
Max(P_Cena) * sum(kolicina) as P_Iznos, 
Max(datum) as datum, 
Max(Golemina) as Golemina


into #tmp_stocks
from [dbo].[Stocks]
group by Barkod
--------------------------------
;
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Stocks]
;
--------------------------------


select *
into [dbo].[Stocks]
from #tmp_stocks with (nolock)
;
drop table #tmp_stocks
;

COMMIT TRAN

END
```

In **Delphi** I execute the command with the following code:

```
RepairStocks.Close;
RepairStocks.SQL.Clear;
RepairStocks.SQL.Add('EXEC [dbo].[RepairStocks]');
RepairStocks.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: Try using the `with (nolock)` hint i.e. `...from [dbo].[Stocks] with (nolock)`. make sure `Barkod` is indexed. use local temporary tables, and a single transaction (as suggested in the answer) with `LEVEL SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: what components are you using? tadoquery? tsqlquery?

Answer (score 4):

You should wrap it in a serializable transaction

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRAN
     ...
COMMIT TRAN
```

Additionally, you may be able to use `truncate` instead of `drop` on the table to empty it, and you could use a local temporary table (`#Stocksss`) or a table variable (`@Stocksss`) instead of a user table

Comment: I tried with 
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRAN
     ...
COMMIT TRAN
I also used temporary tables (#tmp_Stocks) It works good in SQL Management Studio. When I execute it on Delphi I get deadlock error again with different ID

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not best way but it worked for me and I get the results I should get.
Also I don't get any error when I execute this in Delphi

@podiluska - Your suggestion worked in SQL Server Management Studio

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RepairStocks]
AS
BEGIN

begin tran

delete from stocksss


--insert from Stocks to Stocksss
INSERT INTO stocksss
select Barkod, 
sum(kolicina) as Kolicina, 
Max(Kategorija) as Kategorija,
Max(Artikal) as Artikal, 
Max(Opis) as Opis, 
Max(N_cena) as N_cena,
Max(N_cena) * sum(kolicina) as N_Iznos, 
Max(P_cena) as P_cena, 
Max(P_Cena) * sum(kolicina) as P_Iznos, 
Max(datum) as datum, 
Max(Golemina) as Golemina
from [dbo].[Stocks]
group by Barkod
;

----------------------------------------------------------

delete from Stocks

insert into Stocks
select * from stocksss
;

Commit Tran

END
```

Thank you!